# Working with Sets as Functions

Tags: scala, functional-programming, abstraction, higher-order-functions

From a [FP](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) course:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean  // Predicate

  /**
   * Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
   */
  def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
```

Why would that make sense?

```
assert(contains(x => true, 100))
```

Basically what it does is provide the value `100` to the function `x => true`. I.e., we provide 100, it returns **true**.

But how is this related to sets?

Whatever we put, it returns `true`. Where is the sense of it?

I understand that we can provide our own set implementation/function as a parameter that would represent the fact that provided value is inside a set (or not) - then (only) this implementation makes the `contains` function be filled by some sense/meaning/logic/functionality.

But so far it looks like a nonsense function. It is named `contains` but the name does not represent the logic. We could call it `apply()` because what it does is to apply a function (the 1st argument) to a value (the 2nd argument). Having only the name `contains` may tell to a reader what an author might want to say. Isn't it too abstract, maybe?

Comment: Try thinking of `x => true` as the set of all ints :)  Beyond that, remember that the Set type being defined here is more for instructional purposes, rather than production code.

Comment: I'm trying.. :) I wonder though that the more scala I use the more math-related stuff I'm invoking into. That's maybe not so bad.
http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/coding-while-learning-it-at-college.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the code snippet you show above, any set `S` is represented by what is called its *characteristic function*, i.e., a function that given some integer `i` checks whether `i` is *contained* in the set `S` or not. Thus you can think of such a characteristic function `f` like it was a set, namely

> {`i` | all integers `i` for which `f i` is `true`}

If you think of any function with type `Int => Boolean` as set (which is indicated by the type synonym `Set = Int => Boolean`) then you could describe `contains` by

> Given a set `f` and an integer `i`, `contains(f, i)` checks whether `i` is an element of `f` or not.

Some example sets might make the idea more obvious:

```
Set                                Characeristic Function
 empty set                          x => false
 universal set                      x => true
 set of odd numbers                 x => x % 2 == 1
 set of even numbers                x => x % 2 == 0
 set of numbeers smaller than 10    x => x < 10
```

**Example:** The set {1, 2, 3} can be represented by

```
val S: Set = (x => 0 <= x && x <= 3)
```

If you want to know whether some number `n` is in this set you could do

```
contains(S, n)
```

but of course (as you already observed yourself) you would get the same result by directly doing

```
S(n)
```

While this is shorter, the former is maybe easier to read (since the intention is somewhat obvious).

Comment: That's helpful. All this is another alternative type of abstraction for me. Like having Int=>Boolean kind of 'interface'/abstraction for all functions that would have similar 'contract'. One thing only in mind for now: then having a test assert(contains(x => true, 100)), it is not enough to say that this actually tests the "contains" function. What I need to test is that contains().

And what I subconsciously want to do is rename 'Set' to something like 'SetFunction' or "IsContainFunction" ..

Comment: ... or whatever to know that it is not actually a Set but function that provides me the information about what is inside some hypothetical Set if it was existing in real.

Answer (score 2):

Sets (both mathematically and in the context of computer representation) can be represented in various different ways. Using characteristic functions is one possibility. The idea is that a subset S of a given universal set U is completely determined by a function f:U-->{true,false} (called the characteristic function of the subset). simply since you can treat f(u) as answering the question "is u an element in S?".

Any particular choice of representing sets has advantages and disadvantages when compared to other methods. In particular, some representations are better suited to be modeled in a functional language than in imperative languages. If we compare managing sets as characteristic functions vs. as (either sorted or unsorted) lists (or arrays), then, for instance, creating unions, intersections, and set difference, is very efficient with characteristic functions but not so efficient with lists. Checking for the existence of an element is as easy as computing f(-) with characteristic functions, as opposed to searching a list. However, printing out the elements in the set is immediate with a list, but may require lots of computations with a characteristic function.

Having said that, a fundamental difference is that with characteristic functions one can model infinite sets, while this is impossible with array. Of course, no set will actually be infinite, but a set like (x: BigInt) x => (x % 2) == 0 truly represents that set of all even integers and one can actually compute with it (as long as you don't try to print all the elements).

So, every representation has pros and cons (duh).

Comment: mathematical. that's it. That's why probably I have an intention to rename 'Set' to something like 'SetFunction' or "IsContainFunction" to show that this is actually a function but not a Set. 

Because every time when I see 'Set' I tend to think that it is real Set that has some values in it that I can see and feel.

Comment: I think the argument is that a function is just as much a 'real' Set as the collection-of-elements you consider real. Aside: you may find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice an entertaining read.

Comment: @ses you need to make the distinction here between the way you think of a concept (i.e., what it *realy* is (whatever real may be)) and how that concept is modeled. You seem to be thinking of a set as a bag with things in it. It may be most natural for you to model it as an array. The array will be the representation of the *real* set. But notice that representing it as a characteristic function is only changing the representation. The same ideal notion of set is modeled by it. That is why you call the data type Set (not SetFunction) and Contain (not ContainFUnction). For the user it's a set.