# representing sets with lambda functions

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, set

I am struggling with understanding what I really need to do, and would like some outside input or a point to a good reference.  I have been asked to use procedural representation to "implement sets of numbers." Each set will be a one argument function that takes a number and decides if the number is in the set. A few functions (that I have read can be defined in one line) that I have to create:

1. A function that returns a function taking a number as an argument and checks if the number is in the set.
2. A union function that returns the set of all elements in arg1 or arg2
3. Intersection function of above
4. Function that returns elements in arg1 but not arg2
5. etc.

Now I know this is simply enclosing a lambda function, but I guess I am confused on how to represent a set and check it within the lambda function? If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: I wonder if you're misreading some of these, a bit.  Particularly, number 4.  In general, if you can define a set by, e.g., `{x | x > 2}` (the set of numbers greater than two), you can identify it with the function `(lambda (x) (> x 2))`, because that function is enough to identify the elements of the set:  The function returns true when called with `n` if and only if `n` is in the set.  So number 4 would return any elements, but rather a new function representing the set containing elements in the first set, but not in the second.  These functions are typically called characterstic, or

Comment: [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).  Also, can you clarify number 1?  What does the first function take as arguments?  What does the function that it returns take as arguments?

Comment: Maybe the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995988/working-with-sets-as-functions) is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to realise that the first function in your TODO list is the constructor. The rest falls out from there I think.

```
(define (make-set x) (lambda (y) (eq? x y)))
(define (union x y) (lambda (z) (or (x z) (y z))))
(define (intersection x y) (lambda (z) (and (x z) (y z))))
(define (difference x y) (lambda (z) (and (x z) (not (y z)))))

(define set-5 (make-set 5))
(set-5 4)
(set-5 5)

(define set-45 (union (make-set 4) (make-set 5)))
(set-45 3)
(set-45 5)

(define set-34 (union (make-set 3) (make-set 4)))

(define set-4 (intersection set-34 set-45))
(set-4 3)
(set-4 5)
(set-4 4)

(define set-3 (difference set-34 set-45))
(set-3 4)
(set-3 5)
(set-3 3)
```