# Currying using Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I have three functions for a practice exam that I am struggling on.

A function that takes a predicate "pred" and a set "x" and returns whether or not the predicate is true for all elements in the set.

What I was trying:

```
(define (all? pred x)
  (lambda (t) 
    (equal? (pred t) x)))
```

Since pred t returns the subset of x where the predicate is true, I was trying to compare it to the original set... Which obviously isn't the way to do it.

A function that takes an operation "op" and a set "x" and returns a new set where basically the op function has been mapped to the entire set. Basically the equivalent of map, so you'd think I shouldn't be asking for help on this...

What I am trying:

```
(define (map op x)
  (lambda (t) 
    (map (op t))))
```

I must be missing some basic aspect of currying because I feel like these operations should be simple..

Comment: You need to know the interface to `set` to answer this question.

Comment: None of the operations described seem to require currying. What's going to be the curried parameter in each one?

Comment: What @AdamBurry asked is important. Is this using the same set representation that you mentioned in your earlier question, [representing sets with lambda functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19129413/1281433), wherein a set is represented by its characteristic function which return, given a potential element, returns true if the element is in the set, and false otherwise.  E.g., where `(lambda (x) (> x 2))` is the set of numbers greater than two, and `even?` is the set of even numbers?

Comment: If you are still using that representation where sets are represented by their characteristic function, I don't see how you could do this.  If `f` represents some set, so that `(f x)` is true if and only if `x` is in the set, you still wouldn't have a way to list all the elements of the set (indeed, the set might have infinitely many elements).  If you just want a “set” whose elements are those of `f` which also satisfy some predicate `p`, then, since `p` also represents a set, can't you use the “intersection” of `f` and `p`?  I.e., can't you use `(lambda (x) (and (f x) (p x)))`?

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to do something like [andmap](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=andmapo#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/map..rkt%29._andmap%29%29)

You could define a function that evaluates a list to see wether all their elements are #t values.

```
(define full-true?
  (λ (lst)
   (if (empty? lst) #t
     (if (car lst) (full-true? (cdr lst))
         (car lst)))
))
```

Then, your main function would be:

```
(define for-all?
 (lambda 
   (pred lst-of-items)
    (full-true? (map (lambda (x) (pred x)) lst-of-items))
))
```