# Set as function: why map works as loop?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm evaluating task for [Scala FP course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-functional-programming/programming/Edqdi/functional-sets), where set [represents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995988/working-with-sets-as-functions) as function.

And I need to implement map function, which transforms all elements of specified set to another set.

```
  type FunSet = Int => Boolean
  ...

  /**
   * Returns a set transformed by applying `f` to each element of `s`.
   */
  def map(s: FunSet, f: Int => Int): FunSet
```

I'm defined map function with iteration in case of set range (from `-bound` to `bound`):

```
def map(s: FunSet, f: Int => Int): FunSet = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(element: Int, currentSet: FunSet): FunSet = {
      if (element > bound)
        currentSet
      else if (!contains(s, element))
        loop(element + 1, currentSet)
      else
        loop(element + 1, union(currentSet, singletonSet(f(element))))
    }

    loop(-bound, filter(singletonSet(-bound), x => x != -bound))
  }
```

`contains` function defined as:

```
 /**
   * Indicates whether a set contains a given element.
   */
  def contains(s: FunSet, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
```

`filter` function defined as:

```
 /**
   * Returns the subset of `s` for which `p` holds.
   */
  def filter(s: FunSet, p: Int => Boolean): FunSet = intersect(s, p)
```

`union` function defined as:

```
  /**
   * Returns the union of the two given sets,
   * the sets of all elements that are in either `s` or `t`.
   */
  def union(s: FunSet, t: FunSet): FunSet = (e: Int) => s(e) || t(e)
```

`singletonSet` defined as:

```
/**
   * Returns the set of the one given element.
   */
  def singletonSet(elem: Int): FunSet = (x: Int) => elem == x
```

But I was very surprised to see another implementation of `map` function:

```
 /**
   * Returns whether there exists a bounded integer within `s`
   * that satisfies `p`.
   */
  def exists(s: FunSet, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def iter(a: Int): Boolean = {
      if (contains(intersect(s, p), a)) true
      else if (a == 1000) false
      else iter(a + 1)
    }

    iter(-1000)
  }

  /**
   * Returns the intersection of the two given sets,
   * the set of all elements that are both in `s` and `t`.
   */
  def intersect(s: FunSet, t: FunSet): FunSet = (e: Int) => s(e) && t(e)

  ...

  def map(s: FunSet, f: Int => Int): FunSet = y => exists(s, (x: Int) => f(x) == y)
```

Now `map` function using another `exists` function as function composition.
But I don't understand how it works.

1. How can the open variable `y` be interpreted? And why we can define it in that case?
2. `map` function still iterates over function domain range (from -bound to bound), but how such lambda executes as loop?

Comment: It works only because results are checked in the assumed range (-1000, 1000). If you assume all possible inputs of a predicate, you can just iterate over them to check which pass and calculate set for this characterization function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_(mathematics)). `y` is just value tested to be in set just like in any other `FunSet` implementations.

Comment: But who applying `y` in specified range?

Comment: You, when you call `set(item)`. Function returning `true` equals, `item` is in `set`. Checking if `item` belong to some combination of sets, equals checking if combinations of functions yield `true`. If you assume some finite, iterable amount of inputs `map` can be expressed with `exists` because you are literally bruteforcing output set.

Comment: Nope, I meant, who applying `y` to map function, because it's open variable. As example: `def f(s: FunSet, p: Int => Int) = (y: Int) => exists(s, (x: Int) => f(x) == y)`. For `f` invocation, I need to carrying set and `y` in that way `f(someSet, x => x * 2)(1)`.

Comment: `y` is _an argument_ in lambda, it is applied by whoever calls that lambda. You call that lambda, `y` gets some value, lambda's body passes it over. `map` is taking old set - old lambda - and created a new set - a new lambda.

Comment: I suspect that you didn't fully grasp all `type FunSet = Int => Boolean` implications. This `Int` is not provided magically by someone - we are truly setting an equality between `x is in y set` and `y yields true for x argument`. Therefore calculating a new set is equal to defining a new predicate (as lambda). It's all lambdas and combining functions until at some point you are actually checking if some value belongs to a set. Then that value gets pass down all these combined functions and e.g. your `y` gets its value.

Comment: My fault, I'm tested `map` function via special print function, which invoked it with specified range, that's why I saw in output all ranges. Yep, it's now looks clean, thank you!

Comment: Bwt, such print function was defined by course authors, that's why easily missed it.